# Я использую WebSocket (nodeJS) и мне необходимо чтобы телефон мог увидеть мой localhost на ПК

Tags: node.js, websocket

Я использую WebSocket (nodeJS)  и мне необходимо чтобы телефон мог увидеть мой localhost на ПК.

````
    const WebSocket = require('ws');
    
    const server = new WebSocket.Server({port: 3000});
    
    server.on('connection', (ws) => {
      ws.on('message', (message) => {
        server.clients.forEach(client => {
          if(c

lient.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        ws.send(message);
      }
    });
  });
});```

Клиент:

    ```
    let form = document.querySelector(`#form`);
    let input = document.querySelector(`#input`)
    let statusUser = document.querySelector(`#statusUser`);
    let message = document.querySelector(`#message`);
    
    const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:3000`);
    
    function setStatusUser(value) {
      statusUser.innerHTML = value;
    }
    
    function addMessage(value) {
      const li = document.createElement('li');
    
      li.innerHTML = value;
      message.appendChild(li);
    }
    
    
    ws.onopen = () => setStatusUser('ONLINE');
    ws.onmessage = response => addMessage(response.data);
    ws.onclose = () => setStatusUser('OFFLINE');
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
      evt.preventDefault();
    
      ws.send(input.value);
      input.value = '';
    });```
````